# Relationship between independent and dependent variables

Tags: machine-learning, regression, correlation

I have a dataset in which there are multiple independent variables which might have some relation with the dependent variable. I am trying to find the relation between each independent variable at first visually plotting scatterplots between each independent and dependent variable and correlation. But it seems not helping me.

What I am able to think is that it might happen that when I am looking at the relationship of feature1 with label and not able to find a good relation, the other variable feature2 or feature3 might have affected the relationship. How can I keep one variable unaffected by the other variable and see the relationship.

I have actually checked the multicollinearity between different features using VIF and correlation.

P.S. : I am actually trying to fit a regression model

Answer (score 0):

If the correlation indicates no relationship between the investigated variable then you have to drop that feature after justifying the drop with an exhaustive EDA, then try to check the effect of other variables on your dependent variable if EDA suggests positive results then you can fit a reg model.
Thanks